# Show $A=\{x\in [0.1]\mid \exists\, n \in N\; \exists\, k\in \{0,\ldots, 2^{n} \}, \; x=\frac{k}{2^n} \}$ dense in [0.1]

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof, mathematical-french

> Let $$\rm{A}=\left\{x\in [0.1]\mid \exists\, n \in \mathbb{N}\; \exists\, k\in \{0,\ldots, 2^{n}  \},  \; x=\dfrac{k}{2^n} \right\} $$
>   Show that A is dense in $[0.1]$

$A$ is dense in $[0.1] \iff 
\begin{cases} 
    A\subset [0.1] \\ \\
    \forall x,y\in [0.1] \quad \left(x<y \implies \exists\; a\in A ,\;  x<a<y \right) 
\end{cases}$

- $A\subset [0.1]$
- Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and Let $x,y\in [0.1]$ such that $x<y$ then $y-x>0$ thus

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left( 2^{n}(y-x)\right)=+\infty$$ so 
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left( 2^{n}(y-x)\right)=+\infty\iff \forall R\in \mathbb{R}\;\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\quad \left(n\geq N\implies 2^{n}(y-x)> R \right) $$

In particular $$\exists n \in\mathbb{N}\quad 2^{n}(y-x)>2  $$
i.e. $$\exists n \in\mathbb{N}\quad 2^{n}y-2^{n}x>2  $$

then there exists at least $k\in (2^{n}x,2^{n}y)$ 
In particular  $$\exists n \in\mathbb{N}\quad x<\dfrac{k}{2^{n}} <y $$

since $x,y\in[0.1]$ then $$0\leq x<\dfrac{k}{2^{n}} <y\leq 1 $$ i.e.
$$0\leq k \leq 2^{n}$$ 
Thus $$\exists n\in\mathbb{N} \quad k\in \{0,\ldots, 2^{n}  \}\quad x<\dfrac{k}{2^{n}} <y  $$
thus
$$\forall x,y\in [0.1] \quad \left(x<y \implies \exists\; a=\dfrac{k}{2^{n}} \in A ,\;  x<a<y \right)$$

- Is my proof correct
- could someone prove it by reasoning called analysis synthesis 
  [Raisonnement par analyse-synthèse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raisonnement_par_analyse-synth%C3%A8se)

Comment: "Is my proof correct(?)" Yes. "could someone prove it by reasoning called analysis synthesis" Sorry but, *what for?*

Comment: this kind of reasoning let you find the $a\in A$ easly should i write post explain this kind of reasoning since there is no definition for it in english

Comment: For an explicit $a$, try $$a=2^{-n-1}\cdot\lfloor2^n\cdot(x+y)\rfloor$$ for every $n$ such that $$y-x>2^{-n}$$

Comment: how did you choose it correctly ? so in french textbook we use reasoning by analysis and synthesis which let us to Choose Sophisticated $a$

Comment: I used that $|u-\lfloor u\rfloor|<1$ for every $u$. Did you try to show this $a$ works?